# How to scroll nested?

Tags: flutter

I want to scroll in multiple layers. So the _buildheader section is fine as it is - it is always on the top. But now my goal is to scroll through IntroductionTextWidget and stop right at the point where SearchBarWidget is still visible. The ListViewsWidget should scroll through the Searchbar. How can I implement that kind of behaviour?

The ListViewsWidget has multiple ListView.builder()'s if thats any important.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<HomePageViewModel>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column( 
        children: [
          Padding( 
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, right: 25.w, top: 60.h),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  _buildHeader(), 
                  SizedBox(height: 30.h),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
          Expanded( 
            child: SingleChildScrollView( 
              child: Column(children: [
                IntroductionTextWidget(),
                SizedBox(height: 35.h),
                SearchBarWidget(),
                SizedBox(height: 22.h),
                ListViewsWidget(provider: provider),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```